# One property of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

How to prove this property of limits:
$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)}$?

Also, is there intuition for this result?

Note. I have seen this when learning L'Hospital rule so I am not sure if this is true always.

Comment: If $ f(a)=g(a)=0$.

Comment: If and only if?

Comment: It is sufficient but not necessary: take $f=g$ for example.

Comment: So, in case $f(x) \neq g(x)$ this ($ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)}$) is true only when $f(a) = g(a) = 0$?

Comment: Typical proofs of L'Hospital's Rule mention the hypotheses $f(a) =g(a) =0$ then argue as in your question. You should check this in your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general.  Taking $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$, we look at $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{x - 2}{x^2 - 4} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{1}{x+2} = \frac{1}{4}$$ whereas $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
That said, if $f(a)=g(a)=0$ and $f,g$ are differentiable near $x=a$ with $f',g'$ continuous and $g'(a) \neq 0$, then we have that $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{\frac{g(x)-g(a))}{x-a}} = \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}.$$  My guess is the exercise is meant to get you to prove a simple case of L'Hospital's rule.